# ¿Cómo puedo agregar un botón sobre un Snackbar?

Tags: android, material-design

Estaba revisando la documentación de *material-design* en android, y por lo que pude ver no se recomienda agregar algun boton sobre el *snackBar* solo por el hecho que no debe llamar la atención, lo cual me parece bastante lógico.
Sin embargo, revisando de casualidad una conocida aplicación de aprendizaje de idiomas, me encontré que en un momento se muestra un botón por encima de un *snackBar*, como se muestra a continuación:

[image: snackBar con botón]

La pregunta mía es, ¿Puedo implementar en mi aplicación algo similar a esto?. Hasta ahora tengo algo muy sencillo que es solo mi *snackBar* con un mensaje pero estoy un poco perdido se quisiera agregar un botón ya que en la documentación no se explica. El codigo que tengo es el siguiente:

**.XML**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutContainer"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/crearUsuario"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight=".5"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**.JAVA**

```
private Button btnCrearUsuario;
private LinearLayout linearLayoutContainer;
//OnCreate....
btnCrearUsuario = findViewById(R.id.crearUsuario);
linearLayoutContainer = findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutContainer);
btnCrearUsuario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Snackbar
                .make(linearLayoutContainer, "¡Esto es un SnackBar!", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
            }
        });
```

pd: Lo mas cercano a esto que pude ver es agregar el método *.setAction()* y luego definirle el comportamiento pero el problema es que lo agrega por defecto al final del *snackBar* y necesito que se encuentre debajo del texto citado como en la imagen.

Answer (score -1):

Lo que muestras en la imagen no es un snackbar, eso se llama bottom sheet. Para hacerlo debes crear su layout en un nuevo archivo xml. Luego lo usas así:

```
BottomSheetDialog bottomSheet = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
bottomSheet.setContentView(R.layout.bottom_sheet);
btnCrearUsuario.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        bottomSheet.show();
    }
});
```